# RequestAnimationFrame lags in chrome timeline

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chromium, requestanimationframe

I have a question about Google Chrome and Timeline tab in DevTools.
I use window.requestAnimationFrame() with recursive call:

```
function animateRequestAnimationFrame(element, animation, timing, time) {
    (function nextAnimationFrame() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function (elapsed) {
            var progress = elapsed / time;

            if (progress < 1) {
                animation(element, timing(progress));
                nextAnimationFrame();
            } else {
                animation(element, timing(1));
            }
        });
    })();
}
```

In timeline i see this: [image: DevTools timeline].
Why every RequestAnimationFrame callbacks are not at start of a frames?

Answer (score 0):

Because that's the [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) of `requestAnimationFrame`:

> The window.requestAnimationFrame() method tells the browser that you wish to perform an animation and requests that the browser calls a specified function to update an animation **before the next repaint**. The method takes a callback as an argument to be invoked **before the repaint**.